# Vapor render html from MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, swift, vapor

I'm using vapor framework and created a table with longText type in mysql & store text with html tags in it,

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |       content        |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | <b>title</b>sometext |
+----+----------------------+
```

now when i show them in leaf, it's shows with html tags like:

```
<b>title</b>sometext
```

My Leaf file:
[image: My Leaf File]
but i want to show like:

**title** sometext

how can i do this?
thanks

Comment: Please remove the picture (which doesn't show the whole table), and post it in your question instead. Try [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: I would guess that the rendering engine does by intension not render the raw HTML.

Comment: @CSharper i don't know exactly, i hope someone tells me how it's done

Comment: I can see if anything like this is possible, but I'm going to guess it's not since you'd want to avoid JS injection. 

Mind if I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: @TWOF i'm not very expert for web developing, do you know another solution other than this?

Comment: It kind of depends why you're doing this. Do you want the styling of the text to change, or should whatever you're inserting onto the webpage always be bold?

Comment: @TWOF no, i want to style my text for example one word be bold another be italic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
<pre class="item-body-text-pre">#raw(post.content)</pre>
```

You can use `#raw(<yourVariableHere>)` to insert unescaped text.